# Setting Token in NSTokenField

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstokenfield

I want to set some tokens in a NSTokenField, when it appears.

[Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/GetSetTokenFields/GetSetTokenFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555-CH9-SW2) says: `setObjectValue:`

I try to set tokens usign setObjectValue

```
tokenField.setObjectValue(["One","Two"])
```

but it doesn't´t compile.

What´s the correct method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`objectValue` is a [property defined in `NSControl`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscontrol/1428849-objectvalue?language=objc). In Objective-C, you can set a value to it, in both property notation or setter method `setObjectValue:`. But in Swift, you always need to use property notation -- simple assignment:

```
tokenField.objectValue = ["One","Two"]
```